# Define a preprocessor macro through CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, c-preprocessor

How do I define a preprocessor variable through CMake?

The equivalent code would be `#define foo`.

Answer (score 533, accepted):

For a long time, CMake had the `add_definitions` command for this purpose. However, recently the command has been superseded by a more fine grained approach (separate commands for compile definitions, include directories, and compiler options).

An example using the new [add_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions):

```
add_compile_definitions(OPENCV_VERSION=${OpenCV_VERSION})
add_compile_definitions(WITH_OPENCV2)
```

Or:

```
add_compile_definitions(OPENCV_VERSION=${OpenCV_VERSION} WITH_OPENCV2)
```

The good part about this is that it circumvents the shabby trickery CMake has in place for `add_definitions`. CMake is such a shabby system, but they are finally finding some sanity.

Find more explanation on which commands to use for compiler flags here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html

Likewise, you can do this per-target as explained in Jim Hunziker's answer.

Comment: From the linked page: "Note This command has been superseded by alternatives:
Use add_compile_definitions() to add preprocessor definitions." Maybe this answer needs an edit?

Comment: In cmake 3.10.2, `add_compile_definitions` throws `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_compile_definitions): Unknown CMake command "add_compile_definitions".`. Had to use `add_compile_options(-D <your-def>)` instead.

Comment: @code_dredd In case of old CMake I would prefer `add_definitions`, see the previous version of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9017635/2

Comment: Hi @ypnos, can you do this "from the outside"?  For example, `cmake -D ADD_COMPILE_DEFINITION=DEBUG_CHESSBOARD ..`.

Comment: @mannyglover I don't think so, but you can set the compiler flags with -D, something along the lines of `cmake -D CMAKE_CXXFLAGS='-DDEBUG_CHESSBOARD'` (not tested)

Comment: It's really new... in fact it's in More Modern CMake (> 3.11). A pain that it's so hard to know when a command was introduced.

Comment: Please specify `cmake --version`. Without it, it gets more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Does CMake define any default definitions to point the compilation is done using CMake?

Comment: @Royi I'm not sure if I get your question. CMake provides default flags for compiling Release, Debug, etc. build types on a specific platform.

Comment: I meant like `MSVC` sets its Macros Definitions, does CMAKE propagate default definitions?

Comment: Yes, that's the ones I am talking about. You can find a list here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html

Comment: @Sandburg You can open the link to the last documentation: `https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions` and start changing the version number down until the page disappears. That would be the version where it not yet exists. In the next move you can go to the `Whats new` section to find a new command or feature. So its not so hard.

Comment: @Andry I agree with Sandburg, it really sucks to have to go to these great lengths.

Comment: @ypnos Two underscores are required: e.g. `cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-DDEBUG_CHESSBOARD'`.

Comment: Thanks @user2023370 Unfortunately I cannot edit my comment anymore.

Answer (score 325):

To do this for a specific target, you can do the following:

```
target_compile_definitions(my_target PRIVATE FOO=1 BAR=1)
```

You should do this if you have more than one target that you're building and you don't want them all to use the same flags. Also see the official documentation on [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html).

Comment: @JimHunziker How is `target_compile_definitions(my_target PRIVATE FOO=1)` different from `set_source_files_properties(foo.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS -DFOO=1)` ?

Comment: @JohnStrood The difference is at scope level. `target_compile_definitions` sets the value for WHOLE executable/library, where as 'set_source_files_properties` sets the value for only the specified file.

Latter command allows for files to compiled using a different language; i.e.:
`set_source_files_properties(compile_me_as_objc.c PROPERTIES -x objective-c`.

Note that `-x objective-c` here is a flag specific to GCC/Clang.

Answer (score 38):

> The other solutions proposed on this page are useful for **some versions of Cmake > `3.3.2`**. Here the solution for the version I am using (i.e., `3.3.2`). Check the version of your Cmake by using `$ cmake --version` and pick the solution that fits your needs. The [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html) can be found on the official page.

With CMake version 3.3.2, in order to create

```
#define foo
```

I needed to use:

```
add_definitions(-Dfoo)   # <--------HERE THE NEW CMAKE LINE inside CMakeLists.txt
add_executable( ....)
target_link_libraries(....)
```

and, in order to have a preprocessor macro definition like this other one:

```
#define foo=5
```

the line is so modified:

```
add_definitions(-Dfoo=5)   # <--------HERE THE NEW CMAKE LINE inside CMakeLists.txt
add_executable( ....)
target_link_libraries(....)
```

**PLEASE NOTE** (as @squareskittles suggests in one of the comment): "if you are using `CMake 3.3.2`, you have to `use add_definitions()` or `target_compile_definitions()`. The more modern command, `add_compile_definitions()`, was not added until `CMake 3.12`."

Answer (score 19):

#### 1.) target_compile_definitions

If you are using CMake 3.X your first choice for adding a preprocessor macro should be [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html).

The reason you should prefer this approach over any other approach is because it granularity is `target` based. IE the macro will only be added to your exe/library.

Here is a common example:

```bash
if (WIN32)
    target_compile_definitions(my_lib PRIVATE   
       # Prevents Windows.h from adding unnecessary includes    
       WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN  
       # Prevents Windows.h from defining min/max as macros 
       NOMINMAX 
    )   
endif()
```

#### 2.) add_compile_definitions

*New in version 3.12.*

Find more explanation on which commands to use for compiler flags here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html

[add_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html) applies macros to any targets that are defined after the call.

Here is the same logic as above with add_compile_definitions.

```bash
add_compile_definitions(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN NOMINMAX)
add_library(my_lib)
```

If you use this approach be careful if you are the [top level project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL.html).
Otherwise if users consume your library using [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) they may have issues.

#### 3.) The other less recommended ways

These approaches really aren't recommended anymore. Due to not being modular, not scaling well, not supporting generator expressions, etc.

- [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html)
- [CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html)

#### Why is target_compile_definitions better/preferred?

- It's much more clear to readers of your CMake code how it works.
- Allows usage of PRIVATE/PUBLIC/INTERFACE if needed. Which can make life easier for consumers of your library.
- It's much more modular.

Applying pre-processor flags (Or any compiler flag) globally can create hidden dependencies in your build.

Essentially think of add_compile_definitions as globals in C/C++. Sometimes you need them, but be careful.

Comment: Alternatively to wrapping target compile definitions in `if()`, you may sometimes want to use generator expressions instead. E.g. `target_compile_definitions(my_lib PRIVATE "$<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN>")`

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to recommend use `target_***` operations instead of `add_***` operations when your solution includes many projects.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example where you can pass values from CMake to C++ code. Say, you want to pass:

- flag, here: BOOST ("true" or "false")
- software version string (e.g., "1.0.0")

I recommend to pass them as strings.

So, when you build software with CMake, you can pass parameters like for example if it was built using the [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) library, the software version is pulled from a CMake variable (so that you change that number only in one place).
See below.

In [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization):

```
add_compile_definitions(
    BOOST="${BOOST}"
    Software_VERSION="${PROJECT_VERSION}"
)
```

In your *.cpp* code:

```
std::cout << "Software version is: " << Software_VERSION << " BOOST: " << BOOST << "\n";
```

Comment: If you want to add preprocessor definition only if CMake boolean variable is TRUE, you may use generator expressions e.g. `target_compile_definitions(some_lib PRIVATE "$<$<BOOL:${MY_CMAKE_VAR}>:MY_PREPROCESSOR_VAR>")`