# How to embed path to resource file / CMake (on linux)

Tags: c++, cmake

I am creating a C++ class which has a constructor like this:

```
MyClass(const std::string& config_file);
```

I.e. a configuration file should be passed to the constructor when instantiating an object. As part of the project I create a default configuration file which will probably be used in ~90% of the cases, and I would like people to be able use my class as:

```
MyClass myInstance(DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE);
```

i.e. I want the symbol 'DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE' to point to the path of configuration file I have created as part of the project. But the problem is that I have no clue where people actually install the library. Is there (CMake ??) trick/best practices here?

I guess could do something like

```
set( DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/app/default_config.json)
```

But then things will not work in the build directory?!

Joakim

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to define the value of `DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE` at compile time?

Comment: I think this is basically a definement (as it can be passed by make something=value)

Comment: @heuristicus: Well ideally at install time, but I do not want a full recompile when installing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define preprocessor macro through CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017573/define-preprocessor-macro-through-cmake)