# How to add preprocessor definition in CMAKE project build by Yocto

Tags: c++, cmake, yocto, recipe, openembedded

I'm working on a existent project that use CMake to configure and generate.
The target is an ARM device, so I build all the system with Yocto/OpenEmbedded.

I manage to build a recipe to build the cmake project.
It looks like that:

```
DESCRIPTION = "FANN LIB"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit cmake

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

PV = "1.0"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/libfann/fann.git;branch=master;protocol=git"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native" 

FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/cmake/"
```

In the code there are "#ifdef DEBUG" that I would like to activate. So I would like to add DEBUG to the C/C++ Flags.

I found that I could use

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "CXXFLAGS='-DDEBUG'"
EXTRA_OECMAKE = "set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DDEBUG")"
```

But both replace all CFlags and that is not what I want (plus it broke compilation!)

I just would like that -DDEBUG is added when calling the compiler! :-)

How can I add a preprocessor definition in a CMake based project in a Yocto recipe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define preprocessor macro through CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9017573/608639)

Comment: @jww: The question you suggest as a duplicate is about "internal" adding the flags, within project's `CMakeLists.txt`. Current question is about "external" adding the flags, specifically in Yocto - quite a different thing.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Yeah, I thought that too. Then I reviewed the accepted answer.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578353/3440745) tells mostly about Yocto way ("external") of setting preprocessor macros. Only its last paragraph notes about `CMakeLists.txt` ("internal") way. But this note is crucial for the external way to work: If the project **rewrites** compiler flags (`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`), then all "external" settings will be lost. So the correct way for the project is **appending** flags instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using this assignment for a target build in my recipe files (also based on cmake):

```
# This flag is also propagated to CXXFLAGS
TARGET_CFLAGS += "-DSOME_FLAG"
```

I'm not sure why CFLAGS are propagated to CXXFLAGS, so you can also try `TARGET_CXXFLAGS` variable in OpenEmbeedded. See [Yocto mega manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-TARGET_CXXFLAGS).

Please note that this will add flags only for a target build (i.e. the result will be used only on target). I see that you  are also building native variant, so `BUILD_CXXFLAGS` might be helpful. There is also `BUILDSDK_CXXFLAGS` for nativesdk variant (this is not your case). These variables are clearly described in [the manual in the CXXFLAGS variable description](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-CXXFLAGS).

By the way, one thing which is related to the CMake: If you use `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DDEBUG")` in your CMakeLists.txt, you need to repeat CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS on the right side, i.e. `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DDEBUG")`, otherwise your flags would be overwritten. Please see [this blog](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/) for more information.

Comment: I set TARGET_CFLAGS. Setting TARGET_CXXFLAGS do not change anything (at least for FANN project)