# Defining preprocessor in modern CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, preprocessor

I'm currently learning CMake and don't want to get bad habits since there is always 2 ways to do something in CMake (old way and modern way from what I have seen)

After reading some documentation about preprocessor in CMake and checking this post:
[Define preprocessor macro through cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017573/define-preprocessor-macro-through-cmake)

I've come to the conclusion that I could either define a preprocessor as :

- `add_compile_definitions(FOO)`
- `target_compile_definitions(myTarget PRIVATE FOO)`
- `add_definitions(-DFOO)`

and after some test they does actually all works as intended and define `FOO`

But now my question is what's the most "modern" way that I should use and what is really the difference between each functions, the only difference I noticed is that if I use `target_compile_definitions(myTarget PUBLIC FOO)` it then define `FOO`in parent target.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*The general trend in modern CMake is to move from global settings to target-centric settings.* Based on this rule alone, `target_compile_definitions()` is the most modern approach. It also allows control of whether the settings are used in the target only (`PRIVATE`), in other targets consuming this target (`INTERFACE`), or both (`PUBLIC`). Internally, it works by modifying the target's properties `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` and `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`.

Next down in terms of being modern is `add_compile_definitions()`. It adds the macro definitions to all targets defined in the current directory and subdirectories; its scope is similar to `include_directories()` in this regard. Internally, it works by modifying the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property of the current directory. So: it's still using the correct "modern" mechanisms, but is directory-oriented instead of target-oriented.

At the bottom of the list, we have the very old function `add_definitions()`. This is really best avoided in modern CMake. While intended for specifying preprocessor definitions (hence its name), it actually allows passing arbitrary compiler options in (which is also why you need to specify `-DFOO` instead of just `FOO` as its argument). It tries to figure out whether the things passed in are actually preprocessor macro definitions, in which case they are moved into the directory's `COMPILE_DEFINTIIONS` property. If they are not identified as such (which can happen for macros with complicated replacement strings), they are left in the list of flags.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, `target_compile_definitions` is the most adequate way of adding preprocessing macros.

The reason `target_compile_definitions(myTarget PUBLIC FOO)` propagates `FOO` to dependencies is also one of the reasons you should use it, as you can properly define them per target instead of per folder. You can now attach these definitions to a target so that dependencies also declare them. If you try creating targets from different folders, you will see this behavior more precisely and see that it actually makes far more sense than the previous very unreliable one.

For instance, on Windows, all the usual "exports" macros should be declared this way and `PRIVATE` so they don't get propagated, as they are really private definitions.

Comment: How do you add something equivalent to `#define VER 3.21` using `target_compile_definitions`?

Comment: `target_compile_definitions( myTarget PUBLIC VER=3.21)` should do the trick.