# How does Tensorflow define preprocessor macros?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, macros, bazel

[`tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/platform.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/platform.h) defines some macros. How does TF set macros like `ANDROID`, `__ANDROID__`, `PLATFORM_GOOGLE`, `RASPBERRY_PI`?

I think bazel BUILD file may preset some macros like cmake ([Define preprocessor macro through cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017573/define-preprocessor-macro-through-cmake)) but I cannot find any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the [.bazelrc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/.bazelrc) file. It defines for instance `build:android_arm --config=android`. This means you can build in bazel with `bazel build --config=android` - I guess that a compiler with target android provides in the system header an `ANDROID` and  `__ANDROID__`  define - so you have not to explicitly modify a `cc_binary` target.

You can also add defines explicitly to a `cc_binary`:

The `cc_binary` target provides a `define` and `copts`  attribute:

```
cc_binary(name, deps, srcs, data, args, compatible_with, copts, defines, deprecation, distribs, exec_compatible_with, features, includes, licenses, linkopts, linkshared, linkstatic, malloc, nocopts, output_licenses, restricted_to, stamp, tags, testonly, toolchains, visibility, win_def_file)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.26.0/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary):

> defines: `List of strings; optional`
>
> List of defines to add to the compile line. Subject to "Make" variable
>   substitution and Bourne shell tokenization. Each string, which must
>   consist of a single Bourne shell token, is prepended with `-D` (or `/D` on
>   Windows) and added to `COPTS`. Unlike `copts`, these flags are added for
>   the target and every rule that depends on it! Be very careful, since
>   this may have far-reaching effects. When in doubt, add "-D" (or /D on
>   Windows) flags to `copts` instead.

I would recommend you to add your define to the `copts` attribute, e.g.:

```
cc_binary(
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    copts =  ["-DMY_DEFINE"],
)
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I think you are saying those macros are set at runtime when user inputs `bazel build` command? Or, if I want to "turn on" those macros, I add `-D` options in BUILD?  I just re-confirm my guess about tf's usage.

Comment: @skytree I modified my answer