# How to #define __LINUX__ in cmake?

Tags: linux, cmake, operating-system

I want to #define **LINUX** in my script using CMake. Below is just a workaround.

```
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    add_definitions( -D__LINUX__ )
ENDIF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
```

I wonder what is the proper way to do.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. Identifiers containing `__` anywhere are reserved for the compiler's internal use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define preprocessor macro through CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9017573/608639)