# Best Practices in embedded C: How to use preprocessor directives to autoconfigurate a project for its specific hardware

Tags: c, precompile

I  have two boards, each with the same mcu as target. The difference is that the peripherals are not 100% the same (lets say they are by maybe 90%). So far my colleague has two macros and he either comments them or not so that #ifdef/#endif can be used to tell the preprocessor which includes to use and which to ignore.

I'm thinking of better ways to do this. I dont like the idea of people having to search for the correct line to comment each time they want the correct build for their hardware system, this should be automated and or better documented imho.

Best I came up with are multiple "build-sets" that would then by called "hardware-1" and "hardware-2" or something (of course more descriptive...). These build sets would then each have different "-I"-options to define the two macros my colleague used already before.

For cmake I found this thread:
[Define preprocessor macro through CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017573/define-preprocessor-macro-through-cmake)

Is this the way to go or are there better ways that are more elegant? How would you solve this situation? The question maybe also goes into "What are the best practices to tackle this"

Thanks for your input
J

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks John, I reformated the question a bit.

Comment: In case of simple projects `#ifdef` might be acceptable. They add a lot of clutter though, so they should only be used when there aren't many differences. Apart from that, it might be better to handle this on the version control level. You could have separate branches in the same repo for example. Or just separate builds linking different files.

Comment: @Lundin yes, I think the two builds is the best solution proposed.

Comment: For more complex scenarios I keep a repo containing all HAL interfaces, which are not to be changed by a specific project then another with the hardware-specific implementations of those HALs. This allows code reuse both of the HAL and the drivers between multiple projects and you end up with libraries of tested and verified code.

Comment: yeah... I think that HAL-approach sounds nice and clean!

Answer (score 1):

Normally one can specify preprocessor defines as part of the compilation command.

```
gcc -Wall -Darduino embedded.c
```

So assuming Linux/Make you could use

```
make clean arduino
```

or

```
make clean atmega2560
```

and simply have two targets named that in the make file.
Each one having a -darduino or -datmega2560 as part of the compile command.

If you are using some sort of IDE like MSVC, on the project properties page, under C/C++ you would find a Preprocessor area, and you can add one or the other as part of the preprocessor defines.

```
Preprocessor Definitions  arduino;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Best I came up with are multiple "build-sets" that would then by
> called "hardware-1" and "hardware-2" or something (of course more
> descriptive...). These build sets would then each have different
> "-I"-options to define the two macros my colleague used already
> before.

You mean `-D`, not `-I`, but yes, defining the macros via the compiler command line is one of the traditional approaches to this.  How you might achieve that depends somewhat on your build system, but with a hand-rolled makefile, it is common to define make variables for target-specific flags, and to put put those, appropriately commented, at the top of the top-level makefile.  Sometimes these are intended to be modified at build time, but sometimes there are just different makefiles, or else which set of flags to used is controlled by the target requested on the `make` command line.

> For `cmake` I found [...]. Is this the way to go or are there better ways that are more elegant?

If you are using `cmake` already then yes, `cmake`'s facilities for adding macro definitions to the compiler command line would be a great approach.  If you are *not* using `cmake` then no, switching to a `cmake`-based build system would be way overkill for just solving the problem described.  For systems where CMake will generate makefiles, it is basically a wrapper for what I already described.

I happen to be a fan of the Autotools.  If you have an Autotools-based build system then there are different ways to set up this sort of thing, but if you don't, then setting up autotooling for just this purpose would be overkill.  It is perhaps worth mentioning, however, that a standard Autotools approach would work by putting the definitions of the adjustable control macros in a header file, and having all the source files include that header.  The Autotools would generate that header programmatically, but that's not essential -- you could set up such a header manually and update it as needed, and that would still solve the problem of knowing where to look for the macro definitions.