# Pass variable using cmake and print it in C program

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to get a value provided to cmake invocation through to C code so it can be printed. It should be passed like this `cmake -DSTR="some text" ..` and then in main.c I would do something like `puts(STR)` to get it printed.

This is what I have so far in CMakeLists.txt, but it does not work:

```
project(proj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

add_definitions(-DSTR)
add_executable(main main.c)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define preprocessor macro through CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017573/define-preprocessor-macro-through-cmake)

Comment: `it does not work:` is very very vague. What happens exactly? What messages are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement this with [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) and an auxiliary file. E.g.

```cpp
// File: support_macros.h.in (auxiliary file)

// This file is generated by CMake. Don't edit it.

#define VAR "@VAR@"
```

```cpp
// File: main.c

#include "support_macros.h"
#include <stdio>

int main()
{
    puts(VAR);
    // ...
}
```

```
# File: CMakeLists.txt

project(proj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Not needed
# add_definitions(-DSTR)
add_executable(main main.c)

# -- Generate support_macros.h from support_macros.h.in
set(IN_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/support_macros.h.in")
set(GENERATED_FILE_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/GeneratedFiles")  
set(OUT_FILE "${GENERATED_FILE_PATH}/support_macros.h")
configure_file("${IN_FILE}" "${OUT_FILE}" @ONLY)

# -- Make sure main.c will be able to include support_macros.h
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE "${GENERATED_FILE_PATH}")
```

Then, call `cmake` passing a value for `VAR`:

```sh
$ cmake .. -DVAR="some text"
```

**Note:** by putting quotes around `@VAR@` in `support_macros.h.in`, your `main.c` will compile even if you don't pass a value for `VAR` to `cmake`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `puts(STR)`, then `STR` has to have `"` inside it. You have to pass the value of the variable with embedded quotes. For simple cases:

```
project(proj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
add_definitions( "STR=\"${STR}\"" )
add_executable(main main.c)
```