# How can you use the #define macro generated by CMake's check_type_size function?

Tags: cmake

CMake's [check_size_type function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/module/CheckTypeSize.html) creates `<variable>_CODE` as a preprocessor macro during configuration. When checking the size of time_t:

```
include (CheckTypeSize)
CHECK_TYPE_SIZE("time_t" SIZEOF_TIME_T)
message("the code for size_time_t is ${SIZEOF_TIME_T_CODE}")
```

this yields

```bash
the code for size_time_t is #define SIZEOF_TIME_T 8
```

But how exactly can you use that in your source code?. Solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9017635/621736) refer to the `add_compile_definitions` function, but that seems to only work for command line arguments and not code that CMake generates

Comment: oh I just saw you already saw a similar Q&A. You're going to show exactly what you're trying (a [mre]). Likely you are doing it wrong.