# Pass output of command line utility to compiler/linker

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags

I want to pass result of the `getconf PAGESIZE` command output as preprocessor define to my program in form of `` -DPAGESIZE=`getconf PAGESIZE` `` for `[[gnu::assume_aligned(PAGESIZE)]]` in custom allocator declaration.

I tried the following:

```
add_definitions(-DPAGESIZE=`getconf PAGESIZE`)
```

But it expanded exactly as `` -DPAGESIZE="\`getconf" ... PAGESIZE` ``, where `...` is contents of other `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*`. I.e. there is an issue with escaping of backticks in `CMakeLists.txt` files.

How to properly pass such an arguments to compiler/linker in `CMakeLists.txt` files? Maybe is there another way to achieve desired?

Also I tried `add_definitions(-DPAGESIZE="$$(getconf PAGESIZE)")` (`$$` expanded as `$` by `cmake`), but `-DPAGESIZE` and the rest part are splitted by `cmake`. `add_definitions("-DPAGESIZE=$$(getconf PAGESIZE)")` makes `cmake` to escape every dollar sign though.

Comment: The answer here might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1468695/3171657

Comment: @usr1234567 Backtick make sense in Bourne shell context. It make shell to run command enclosed in backticks, then to substitute it instead of whole "backticked" expression.

Comment: @Orient: I know but I doubt this will work with CMake. You can see that the backtick is escaped. So you have to verify that it works.

Comment: Finally solved by using ``set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DPAGESIZE=\"`getconf PAGESIZE`\"")``. Seems that escaping in contexts of `add_definitions()` and `set()` differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation for [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html) command, preprocessor definitions, passed to this command, are appended to `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property:

> Flags beginning in -D or /D that look like preprocessor definitions are automatically added to the COMPILE_DEFINITIONS directory property for the current directory.

And content of `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property, according to its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) is always escaped by CMake, so you cannot preserve special meaning of backticks in the build command:

> CMake will automatically escape the value correctly for the native build system

Your may modify CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS manually, as you show in your comment.

The better way is to use `execute_process` command for run needed command at *configuration* stage, and use its output for `add_definitions` command. (Or use this output for create additional header file with `configure_file`).