# Get CMake to declare a target phony

Tags: makefile, cmake, compile-time

I want to generate some *compile* time constants. The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468695/189456) to another question gets me quite close. From my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${CXX_SRCS} compile_time.hpp)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT compile_time.hpp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_time.cmake)
```

This works in the sense that the first time I run `make`, it generates `compile_time.hpp`, so that the values of the variables are defined when I run `make` and not `cmake`. But `compile_time.hpp` is not remade when I rerun `make` or even `cmake` to redo the makefiles.

How can I make the target `compile_time.cpp` be marked as `phony` so that it is always remade? I tried

```
add_custom_target(compile_time.hpp)
```

to no effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) creates a "phony" target: It has no output and is always built. For make some target depended from the "phony" one, use `add_dependencies()` call:

```
add_custom_target(compile_time
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_time.cmake
)
# Because we use *target-level* dependency, there is no needs in specifying
# header file for 'add_library()' call.
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${CXX_SRCS})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} compile_time)
```

Library's dependency from the header *compile_time.h* will be detected automatically by headers scanning. Because script `compile_time.cmake` updates this header unconditionally, the library will be rebuilt every time.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), this will be PHONY also when you *do* use `DEPENDS`. It says: The target has no output file and is always considered out of date even if the commands try to create a file with the name of the target.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Not sure why I have added notion about absence of `DEPENDS`, but "no `OUTPUT`" seems to describe the situation better. The answer is fixed now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out that cmake does NOT create real `.PHONY` targets and there is no way to make it do so. What it does is create a rule for the `OUTPUT` file and then never create that file, so that it is "always out of date". If said file is created, cmake removes it again. I think that was a bad choice because it stops me from doing certain things (as a result I can't use the ExternalProject stuff).